# need information for JWT SSO authentication on drupal 8 and angular application

Tags: angular, jwt, single-sign-on, drupal-8, session-state

I have got a requirement in my organization. It is as follows.

We have two applications. One is developed in angular and the second is in durpal. We have a all the users data in angular application. if user logged in with angular application and switched to drupal application. We are planning to use the same user details with oath jws token mechanism. By which user can access the drupal pages and angular pages with unique user details.

So, Please help me in finding the process of it. Any modules or blogs or any ides who may have already come across of it.

Thanks you for supporting

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935561/) helps you

Answer (score 0):

JWT token should be created and signed on backend with private key. 
Frontend could receive it with login request.

Then you'll be able to send it a new time to other API or with a redirect URL to Drupal for example. (I don't know implementation of Drupal, but I imagine you can catch it when receiving request).

Maybe in your case, you should consider to implement a central IdP/JWT server which is responsible to authenticate user and deliver safe signed JWT. Then you'll be able to connect both Angular app and Drupal app.

[Have a look at this page](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/) or you can also consider using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).

Hope this will help you a little bit.